# Changing the root pointer of a binary search tree

Tags: tree

I was studying Binary Trees. And I found this code for the insertion of a node in the tree. 
Here "root" is a pointer variable of structure type in a class "TreeType" as a "private member".

In this function, "root" is passed by reference, so in the "Insert" function any changes in the "tree" causes change in the "root" as well. If we call Insert function again, the root will be pointing to the last node or it will point to the first node?So, according to me, as it will be pointing to the last node the insert function will no longer work. Can anybody help with this?

```
void Insert(TreeNode*& tree, ItemType item);

void TreeType::InsertItem(ItemType item)
// Calls the recursive function Insert to insert item into tree.
{
Insert(root, item);
}
void Insert(TreeNode*& tree, ItemType item)
// Inserts item into tree.
// Post: item is in tree; search property is maintained.
{
if (tree == NULL)
{// Insertion place found.
tree = new TreeNode;
tree->right = NULL;
tree->left = NULL;
tree->info = item;
}
else if (item < tree->info)
Insert(tree->left, item); // Insert in left subtree.
else
Insert(tree->right, item); // Insert in right subtree.
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see this should work fine except for the case that you have a duplicate. Changes to the tree will NOT effect the root as you have said. I am not sure the problem you are having

Comment: But in passing by reference the value of the source also changes right. Then why not here? Can you elaborate??

Comment: void Insert(TreeNode*& tree, ItemType item); because of TreeNode*&tree

Answer (score 2):

The only time root gets changed is if the tree is empty, so it will still point to the "first node" is such existed in the first place.  In all other cases, the "root" that is being changed is either the left or right child pointer of a node.

Comment: Yes, suppose it goes on pointing to the right child and inserts at appropriate place. Then by that time the root pointer has different value than it should have. So if try to insert again, Will the search start from the pointer where the item was inserted or from the beginning

Comment: The ONLY time the root gets changed is when the tree is empty; any recursive call does NOT change the root, but rather one of the internal pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The Insert code can be better illustrated by the following code which decomposes the problem into three cases:

```
void Insert(TreeNode*& tree, ItemType item)
{
if (tree == NULL)
{
    // Insertion place found.
    tree = new TreeNode;
    tree->right = NULL;
    tree->left = NULL;
    tree->info = item;
    return;
}

if (item < tree->info) {
    if(tree->left == NULL) {
        tree->left = new TreeNode;
    } else {
        Insert(tree->left, item); // Insert in left subtree.
    }
} else {
    if(tree->right == NULL) {
        tree->right = new TreeNode;
    } else {
        Insert(tree->right, item); // Insert in right subtree.
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, when the tree is empty, `root=NULL`. So the first time it will enter into the first `if` clause. Then the root will be created and since the pointer is passed in by reference, that means that the root node will be created on the heap and returned from the function. The new value of the root pointer will be passed to the caller via reference. So the root pointer value will remain in the heap memory. As subsequent tree building is in process, all child nodes will be built subsequently without affecting the root node.

Comment: But I still have some confusion. In function swap(int &a,int &b), changes in the values of a and b reflects in the function from where swap is called. Then why not in the above case in tree.

Comment: That's because when the tree is empty, the root node is created on the heap and yes, its value (the pointer to the root node) gets changed because of the `new` in the first if block. But root node gets assigned only once after the first function call. After that, all subsequent child nodes get assigned by recursion and they don't affect the root node. Think about how recursion works.